# How can I summarize and count multiple column data surrounded by zeros

Tags: r

I am working with climate precipitation datasets and need to identify the length (how many consecutive days) of a precipitation event and then summarize these events by summing the total rainfall of an event. My current dataset looks like this:

```
> head(AcademyPH)
  X     X1_1 X2       X3 X4 X5        X6        X7        X8        X9 X10       X11       X12       X13       X14 X15 X16
1 1 2.802768  0 8.731085  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1541449 0.5672905   0 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.6186382 4.2717023   0   0
2 2 0.000000  0 3.719260  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000   0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.8940655 2.2009878   0   0
3 3 0.000000  0 0.000000  0  0 0.7709681 0.0000000 0.6604212 0.0000000   0 0.0000000 1.9516009 1.3570352 0.0000000   0   0
4 4 0.000000  0 0.000000  0  0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000   0 0.0000000 0.8212746 0.0000000 0.0000000   0   0
5 5 0.000000  0 1.072659  0  0 0.0000000 0.7867589 0.0000000 0.0000000   0 0.2612132 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5075513   0   0
6 6 0.000000  0 2.604247  0  0 0.3344550 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000   0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1674422   0   0
```

In total there are 32 columns of data in the dataframe (each a different climate model). For each model I would like to generate a new column with the count values for the duration of a rain event and a column for the sum of the rainfall for the same rain event. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `colSums` maybe? Assuming 0 means no rainfall TRUE otherwise and the columns refer to values obtained from the models.

Comment: Aren't there 3 events in row 1, all 3 with a duration of  days? How do you expect to create just one column with the duration?

Comment: @RuiBarradas every column is a separate model, so the rain events are consecutive non-zero values in a column not spanning across rows. The answer posted below worked well for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of handling this is to create a column to identify rainfall events, then summarize based on that column.

tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


my.data <- AcademyPH %>%
      gather(key = "Model", value = "Rainfall", 2:17) %>% 
      group_by(Model) %>%
      mutate(Event = cumsum((Rainfall>0&lag(Rainfall, default = 0)==0)|(Rainfall==0&lag(Rainfall, default = 0)>0))) %>%
      group_by(Model,Event) %>%
      summarize(
            Duration = n(),
            EventRainfal = sum(Rainfall),
            MaxRain = max(Rainfall)
      ) %>%
      ungroup()

head(my.data, 10)  # more rows so you can see differences between Event rainfall and max rainfall

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   Model [5]
#   Model Event Duration EventRainfal MaxRain
#   <chr> <int>    <int>        <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 X1_1      1        1        2.80    2.80 
# 2 X1_1      2        5        0       0    
# 3 X10       0        6        0       0    
# 4 X11       0        4        0       0    
# 5 X11       1        1        0.261   0.261
# 6 X11       2        1        0       0    
# 7 X12       0        2        0       0    
# 8 X12       1        2        2.77    1.95 
# 9 X12       2        2        0       0    
#10 X13       1        3        3.87    1.62
```

In the resulting table, each of your original columns are represented under Model, with an value under Event for each period of rain vs dry, how long the event lasted, and how much rain fell.  You could then filter this to only contain rain events (as opposed to dry spells).  To put this into a series of separate column, you could use `spread()` to distribute them under columns with the model name.  I would think in this case you would want separate tables for event duration and rainfall